# How to get HZ with ADB shell

Tags: android, linux-kernel, adb

How can I know HZ value of Android kernel through ADB shell? (without any coding)

I checked [How to check HZ in the terminal?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12480486/how-to-check-hz-in-the-terminal), but this is not work with Android ADB shell.

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## Theory

You can derive the kernel space HZ value by taking an elapsed time in *jiffies* and dividing it by the elapsed time in *seconds*.

You can get both the system uptime in *jiffies* and in *nanoseconds* from the **/proc/timer_list** file.

- System uptime in **nanoseconds**

  - Search for the `now at <nanoseconds> nsecs` line
  - `<nanoseconds>` will be the uptime in *nanoseconds*
- System uptime in **jiffies**

  - Search for the `jiffies: <jiffies>` line (any processor will do)
  - `<jiffies>` will be the uptime in *jiffies*

    - **NOTE:** This value is typically offset forward by [`INITIAL_JIFFIES`](https://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/people/akpm/patches/2.5/2.5.62/2.5.62-mm2/broken-out/initial-jiffies.patch) in the kernel -- so it may not start counting at `0`. Nevertheless, this shouldn't affect the outcome of our calculation since we're concerned with the *elapsed time* rather than *obsolute uptime*.

By taking these two values over an elapsed period of time, you can calculate the HZ value using the following equation:

```
         (jiffies_after - jiffies_before)
HZ = -----------------------------------------
     ((nsecs_after - nsecs_before)/1000000000)
```

---

## Example

If you happen to have `awk` (perhaps via BusyBox), you can automate this calculation:

```
$ awk '/^now at/ { nsec=$3; } /^jiffies/ { jiffies=$2; } END { print nsec, jiffies; system("sleep 1"); }' /proc/timer_list | awk 'NR==1 { nsec1=$1; jiffies1=$2; } /^now at/ NR>1 { nsec2=$3; } /^jiffies/ NR>1 { jiffies2=$2; } END { dsec=(nsec2-nsec1)/1e9; djiff=(jiffies2-jiffies1); print int(djiff/dsec); }' - /proc/timer_list
```

Due to rounding errors, the HZ value may be slightly off; you might want to perform this calculation several times and average it. Most modern kernels have kernel space `HZ` set to `250`.

---

## Breakdown

Here's the same command spread over several lines to clarify how it works:

```
$ awk '
> /^now at/ { nsec=$3; }
> /^jiffies/ { jiffies=$2; }
> END {
>       print nsec, jiffies;
>       system("sleep 1");
> }
> ' /proc/timer_list | awk '
> NR==1 { nsec1=$1; jiffies1=$2; }
> /^now at/ NR>1 { nsec2=$3; }
> /^jiffies/ NR>1 { jiffies2=$2; }
> END {
>       dsec=(nsec2-nsec1)/1e9;
>       djiff=(jiffies2-jiffies1);
>       print int(djiff/dsec);
> }
> ' - /proc/timer_list
```

- `/^now at/ { nsec=$3; }`

  - Save the number of *nanoseconds* to the variable `nsec`
- `/^jiffies/ { jiffies=$2; }`

  - Save the number of *jiffies* to the variable `jiffies`
- `END {`

  - `print nsec, jiffies;`

    - Print out *nanoseconds* and *jiffies* delimited by a space
  - `system("sleep 1");`

    - Sleep for a second to prevent a division by 0 when we calculate the HZ value
- `' /proc/timer_list | awk '`

  - Process the **/proc/timer_list** file
  - Pipe output to a new instance of `awk`
- `NR==1 { nsec1=$1; jiffies1=$2; }`

  - Set the `nsec` and `jiffies` values from the previous `awk` to `nsec1` and `jiffies1` respectively
- `/^now at/ NR>1 { nsec2=$3; }`

  - Save the number of *nanoseconds* to the variable `nsec2`
- `/^jiffies/ NR>1 { jiffies2=$2; }`

  - Save the number of *jiffies* to the variable `jiffies2`
- `END {`

  - `dsec=(nsec2-nsec1)/1e9;`

    - Calculate the *change in seconds*
  - `djiff=(jiffies2-jiffies1);`

    - Calculate the *change in jiffies*
  - `print int(djiff/dsec);`

    - Print out the HZ value as an integer
- `' - /proc/timer_list`

  - Process the **standard input** followed by the **/proc/timer_list** file

Answer (score 3):

Provided you have `busybox` installed:

```
T1=`grep gp_timer /proc/interrupts| busybox awk '{print$2}'`;sleep 1;T2=`grep gp_timer /proc/interrupts| busybox awk '{print$2}'`;echo $((T2-T1))
```

Comment: It should be mentioned that this answer assumes support for the `gp_timer` timer is available in your Android kernel build.