# What is the "timestamp" in /proc/schedstats?

Tags: unix, linux-kernel, scheduler

I am trying to get a more responsive idea of the system run queue length to see if load balancing based on the one minute load average from `sysinfo()` is having issues caused by the client processes perhaps looking in lockstep...

I've managed to find `/proc/schedstats`, and it looks to be what I'm looking for, but...

I want to make sure I base my values on the actual interval between polls of `/proc/schedstat`, instead of potential processing overhead (it's a shell script).

Now for the question: What is the unit of measurement used for the "timestamp" value at the top of the `/proc/schedstats` file? It's sure not nanoseconds, because the value is somewhere between 258 and 260 when my script loops through with a `sleep 1` between loops.

Comment: The ultimate documentation is the kernel source...

Comment: My expectation is that schedstats data is only for the last jiffy? Is that true?

Answer (score 1):

Inspecting [kernel sources sched/stats.c](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/kernel/sched/stats.c#L21) shows that the `timestamp` field is in jiffies.

> What is the unit of measurement used for the "timestamp" value at the top of the /proc/schedstats file?

It's `1/HZ` second, typically with `HZ=300`, the unit would be 3.333 miliseconds if I'm counting right.

Comment: Combined with https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12480486/how-to-check-hz-in-the-terminal I now have it. It's jiffies and it's 250/sec on the hosts I'm using.