# this_thread::sleep_until apparently returned before the specified time

Tags: c++, linux

I want to run some code at the beginning of each minute, my code looks like:

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
int main(){
    using namespace std;
    using namespace std::chrono_literals;
    auto start_ctime = time(NULL)/60*60+60;//beginning second of next minute
    auto until= chrono::system_clock::from_time_t(start_ctime);
    for(;;until+=60s){
        this_thread::sleep_until(until);
        auto diff=time(NULL)-start_ctime;
        cout<<diff<<endl;
    }
}
```

output:

```
0
59
120
180
239
300
```

Seems in some iterations, either

- `sleep_for` returned before the timepoint specified, which doesn't conform with the requirement of it or `nanosleep`(which seems to be called by the implementation).
- Or `time` returns a time before the real time

What could happen? I am using g++ 11.2.0 and Ubuntu 22.04

Comment: `start_ctime = time(NULL)/60*60+60;`. What is the meaning of `time(NULL)-start_ctime;`? Don't you need to divide that one also before subtracting?

Comment: @ÖzgürMuratSağdıçoğlu both are in the format of seconds since epoch. `diff` is the seconds passed since `start_ctime`

Comment: Use `system_clock::now()` instead of `time(NULL)`. As `sleep_until` should be tied to `system_clock`.

Comment: @ALX23z I need to use the C timestamp somewhere else in the program. Per cppreference, `system_clock It is the only C++ clock that has the ability to map its time points to C-style time.` I assume they can perfectly map to each other?

Comment: How can they perfectly represent each other if `time` measures in seconds while `system_clock` measures in nanoseconds? And who knows what other differences there are between the two calls.

Comment: You are right, I was thinking about whole seconds only (in my case) when writing that. In my case `until` is initialized from `time_t` which is a whole second, then added whole seconds. So it should always point to the exact start of each minute. I can see no reason the subsequent `time(NULL)` will return a time less than that, as suggested by the output.

Comment: As far as I see, on Linux at least, the amount of time passed right after first `sleep_until` is about 60.00005214sec according to `chrono::system_clock` I presume that for whatever reason `std::time` thinks the amount of time passed is something about `59.996sec` and rounds it down to `59`. I don't believe they ever required perfect consistency and accuracy between calls of `system_clock` and `std::time` - it might be due to update frequency of the `std::time`, as it returns time in seconds it isn't as accurate as `system_clock`.

Comment: Thanks @ALX23z, I figured out the same.

Answer (score 2):

Due to the cache used by `time`, it may return the last second.

The glibc implementation uses `CLOCK_REALTIME_COARSE`, which depends a cache maintained by linux kernel tick. Seems on all of my machines, the frequency is 10ms.

What happened was there was a tick right before the expected second, keeping the cached time to be the last second, and the thread was woke at the second.

The `this_thread::sleep` looks good, I saw guard code like `do{/*sleep*/} while(now()<expected);` in the C++ implementation and generated assembly.

References:
https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Getting-the-Time.html
http://events17.linuxfoundation.org/sites/events/files/slides/Timekeeping%20in%20the%20Linux%20Kernel_0.pdf

[How to check HZ in the terminal?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12480486/how-to-check-hz-in-the-terminal)